# EntityFramework 4.1 CodeFirst Monitor.Enter

Tags: .net, performance, asp.net-mvc-3, transactions, entity-framework-4.1

I have a problem with EF 4.1. We found a performance issue in the project in one method, I started using dotTrace for resolving the issue, and I've found such strange behavior:
[image]

When application starts - everything is ok, first calls to the method work fine but later the time spent in Monitor.Enter grows each time I perform some actions on site.

I understand that the problem is with locking, and it means that something blocks the calls, but I don't have any idea what is happening there. If I had sources of the EF 4.1 I could try to debug the whole thing, but it's the last thing I would do.
Could you please give me some tips where to look, and what can probably influence such behavior? The first thing I thought are transactions of course but I couldn't find any transactions used in this project, at least explicitly!
You're welcome to write any idea you have, cause I can't find any similar issue on the internet.

Thank you.

Comment: How often are you creating your dbcontext?  What database are you using?

Comment: Per web request, MS SQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an issue in our code. It was, as always, small cause that had huge impact on everything.

As I've already said, in the application there was strange issue - every call to the MVC application and therefore to the EntityFramework was in separate AppDomain. EF CodeFirst builds and compiles model once per AppDomain and in my case it was building and compiling the model every time, cause it was a separate AppDomain. The cause was simple, someone in other team have added filesystem logging to the assembly that was called, and every call to the class of that assembly changed the file and WebServer was restarting the application. I have just turned off the logging and it fixed the problem. Now I don't have this performance issue.

Answer (score 2):

That is quite interesting problem. I just made small quick analysis with help of Reflector .NET (you can also use ILSpy, JustDecompile or DotPeek to see any .NET source code which is not obfuscated). The analysis can be incorrect or based on incorrect assumptions so take it into account.

Let's begin with `InitializeDatabaseAction`:

```
private void InitializeDatabaseAction(Action<InternalContext> action)
{
    Func<Tuple<DbCompiledModel, string>, RetryAction<InternalContext>> valueFactory = null;
    if (!this._inDatabaseInitialization)
    {
        try
        {
            this._inDatabaseInitialization = true;
            if (valueFactory == null)
            {
                // Delegate to create a new instance of RetryAction
                valueFactory = t => new RetryAction<InternalContext>(action);
            }
            // InitializeDatabases is ConcurrentDictionary - it stores information
            // about all compiled models and they related database connection strings
            // This call will try to get existing RetryAction for the model and if
            // it doesn't exists it will use current valueFactory to create
            // a new instance and add it to dictionary. It will also return
            // that value and execute its PerformAction operation.
            // If you have just one context and one database you will have only
            // single record in the concurrent dictionary but every creation
            // of your DbContext will go through this call to ensure that database
            // is initialized. This code is executed when your context is used
            // for data retrieval or persistence for the first time.
            InitializedDatabases.GetOrAdd(Tuple.Create<DbCompiledModel, string>(this._model, this._internalConnection.ConnectionKey), valueFactory).PerformAction(this);
        }
        finally
        {
            this._inDatabaseInitialization = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now let's check `RetryAction` class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Adapted from Lazy<> to allow the initializer to take an input object and 
/// to do one-time initialization that only has side-effects and doesn't 
/// return a value. 
/// </summary>
internal class RetryAction<TInput>
{
    // Fields
    private Action<TInput> _action;
    private readonly object _lock;

    // Methods
    public RetryAction(Action<TInput> action)
    {
        this._lock = new object();
        this._action = action;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs the action unless it has already been successfully 
    /// performed before. 
    /// </summary> 
    public void PerformAction(TInput input)
    {
        // Here we have Monitor.Enter
        lock (this._lock)
        {
            if (this._action != null)
            {
                Action<TInput> action = this._action;
                this._action = null;
                try
                {
                    action(input);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    this._action = action;
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you have many concurrent threads (your ASP.NET MVC application is under heavy load) and you are creating a lot of DbContext instances the `lock` in perform action can be really a problem for your throughput. I believe this can be considered as a bug and it has quite simple fix which can improve throughput in most cases:

```
public void PerformAction(TInput input)
{     
    // This is known as Double-Checked Locking  
    if (this._action != null)
    {
        lock (this._lock)
        {
            if (this._action != null)
            { 
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second problem in your trace follows the same problem.

I suggest you to once more validate that this is really source of your problems (it should not be problem for a few calls because lock contention is problem of heavy load) and open bug on [MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/) or post it to [ADO.NET team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/contact.aspx). You can reference this post as description of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think that this is our issue somehow, cause we don't have any heavy load. dotTrace shows decompiled sources of the methods so I have seen the code already, but I don't understand  what can be wrong with our code that it behaves like this. We have creation of DbContext per web request, is it good that every call the InitializeDatabaseAction is called? Cause I tried to use the same DbContext for several calls to the same method and it doesn't go so far - it runs fast when reusing the context.

Comment: I have investigated further and I found that our MVC app creates controllers in different AppDomains, as I remember DbContext's OnModelCreating is called first time per AppDomain. So could it be a case when several AppDomain's trying to create the model everytime and they wait for each other?

Comment: No because `Monitor` is scoped to single AppDomain. Anyway if your MVC application manually creates domain there can be a lot of additional challenges resulting in this issue. Let IIS handle domains.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I forgot about that, thought that it could lock on data somehow when reading from db or smth.
About domains I have covered it here, I don't create appdomains myself:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233257/asp-net-mvc-requests-in-different-application-domains

Comment: Our application doesn't create AppDomains, it's the WebServer (in my case vs 2010 development server) So I don't know what to do now! Am I right that model is created once per appdomain? And in my case if every controller runs each time in different AppDomain and DbContext is created for each controller, then performance will be bad? My OnModelProcessing hits every time I have a call to the controller.

Comment: FYI: I have added an item to our backlog to look at adding double-checked locking to RetryLazy.